# Landing page builder for my customers but sold by me

Tags: forms

let's say I have the domain domain.com.
Now I am looking for a landing page builder that I can sell through my domain, which is showed on my domain but not hosted by me.

For example the user logs into his account in domain.com and can then create and edit his templates. However all data is not stored on my domain but on that page builder provider. But the user does not see this and uses it through our domain and it's also not a referral program.

Is there such a provider?

Comment: You want to resell web pages along with the tool to create a landing page? Is that right?

Comment: We want to offer the users advertising tools and courses and they should be able to create landingpages for their businesses under our domain. But we do not want to store that landingpages on our servers. So basically we help them push their business depending on their membership and also help them create a landingpage without hosting those or storing any referral/lead data. We do not resell the web pages/landingpages but we help to grow their business with courses.